# Create Apple script / Automator's app for find/replace in PDF files

Tags: pdf, automator, find-replace

I have a small problem with PDF files that I export from Figma.

1. I make a text link in Figma file
2. I export PDF with this text
3. I open PDF in Acrobat (or whatever viewer) and I see my link in black box (with thin black lines around text)

After some googling I've found this solution:

1. Open PDF in text editor
2. Find string "/Link" and replace with "/Link /Border [0 0 0]"

Now in my workflow I have tons of these PDF files with links.
I was wondering if I can make some script or app, where I can drop PDF and it will replace this strings and rewrite PDF back

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

I tried lots of searches, but found more people with same problem.
The only solution now is manually find/replace in text editor.

Comment: Yes, this replace works perfect: no other variants needed. I was looking for a script version of this replacement. For me it looks pretty easy (since i'm no-code designer): dropping PDF to this app/script and have it back with replacement. May be i'm wrong though)

Comment: Made working code

`on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "TextEdit"
        open item 1 of input
        set theDocument to document 1
        set theText to text of theDocument
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "/Link"
        set theTextItems to every text item of theText
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "/Link /Border [0 0 0]"
        set theModifiedText to theTextItems as string
        set text of theDocument to theModifiedText
        save theDocument
        close theDocument
    end tell
    return input
end run`